# Setting an image from drawable equal to a variable at runtime

Tags: android, drawable

I have two images in my drawable folder, one called "Red" and the other called "Yellow". I am trying to set these images equal to two variables, one currently called "redchip" and the other called "yellowchip". Both redchip and yellowchip are declared as integers.

Can I set the R.drawable image integer values equal to my variables, and if so, how?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by setting an image equal to an integer.  Do you mean you want to generate a picture of the value?

Comment: Maybe he meant `R.drawable.red` and `R.drawable.yellow` resource integer ids. Please confirm, Tom.

Comment: hi chris, yes thats what I mean. In essence I want my code to look like:

Comment: whoops, here is what I was hoping for it to look like
 
int redchip = Red; (from my drawble)
int yellowchip = Yellow; (from my drawble)

Comment: hi inazaruk, that is what I meant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I have done in the past is use a map in a util class to return the drawable's integer id.

Example:

```
public class DrawableUtil{
   public static final int KEY_CHIP_YELLOW = 0;
   public static final int KEY_CHIP_RED = 1;

   private Map<Integer, Integer> drawableMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

    DrawableUtil(){
        drawableMap.put(KEY_CHIP_YELLOW, R.drawable.yellowchip);
        drawableMap.put(KEY_CHIP_RED, R.drawable.redchip);
    }

    public int getYellowChip(){
        return drawableMap.get(KEY_CHIP_YELLOW);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm still a bit confused about KEY_CHIP_YELLOW and KEY_CHIP_RED. what is their purpose?

Comment: Those are the static constant Integers used to identify the chips.  I will add that to my solution.

Comment: okay that makes sense, thanks. This was exactly what i was looking for, appreciate it!